# java in command line not working in genexus

Tags: java, shell, web, genexus

I have a problem with this:

```
C:\Proyectos\ReciboElectronico\JavaRE\web>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java.exe" -cp gxclassd.zip;.;iText.jar;./drivers/ojdbc6.jar arecibonom param1 param2
```

This command works perfectly fine directly in the command line but it doesn´t work in Genexus.

I use it like this in Genexus:

```
&comando    = 'C:\Proyectos\ReciboElectronico\JavaRE\web "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java.exe" -cp gxclassd.zip;.;iText.jar;./drivers/ojdbc6.jar arecibonom param1 param2'

&resshell   = shell(&comando,1) 
MSG(&resshell.ToString())
&comando in varchar(500)
&resshell is Numeric(10,0)
```

The MSG output is 1, so it means is not working.

I hope someone can help me please. What is wrong with the sentence in Genexus?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this:

```
&comando = 'C:\Proyectos\ReciboElectronico\JavaRE\web "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java.exe" -cp gxclassd.zip;.;iText.jar;./drivers/ojdbc6.jar arecibonom param1 param2'
```

be rather:

```
&comando = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java.exe" -cp gxclassd.zip;.;iText.jar;./drivers/ojdbc6.jar arecibonom param1 param2'
```

?